# cap deploy works from office but not from home network

Tags: capistrano

I'm trying to get a little work done over the weekend and want to stage some stuff. I can deploy in the office fine but when I run cap deploy from home I get the following error:

Permission denied (publickey)

If my public key works in the office shouldn't work from as well? I have also checked any firewall policies with our hosting.

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to **.***.***.** [**.***.***.**] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/*******/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/*******/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/*******/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/*******/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ***********************************
debug1: Host '**.***.***.**' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/*******/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/*******/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/*******/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: I've had this when I have SSH keys that need to be added, after a reboot or something similar.  Have you tried `ssh-add ~/.ssh/`?

Comment: no that didn't seem to help

Comment: It almost sounds like there's a proxy from your office that SSH goes through from the office that doesn't exist outside...  Can you straight SSH to the box, perhaps using `-v` for verbose output?

Comment: Yes, I can ssh in fine. I should have noted that before. I have pasted the output above. I also should have noted I have done this before successfully on my previous machine. I'm really not certain what's different here.

Comment: Never mind, turns out I got back to the office and deploy didn't work there either... awesome! At least it makes a little more sense now though.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of Googling ... Check this out:  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135000

TL;DR - I'm guessing your machine gets assigned a hostname that the server recognizes and then allows to authenticate.  When you're on your home network, you're likely assigned something different that the server doesn't recognize, therefore not allowing you access.

I keyed off of this line in your log file:  `debug1: Roaming not allowed by server`

In the thread linked to above, it sounds like a person with a similar problem was able to solve their issue by updating their machine's hostname when on their home network.  Might be worth a shot.